# Advanced Custom Field Gallery Include once error No such file or directory

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Gallery add-on plugin. In my functions file I have:

```
include_once(‘acf-gallery/acf-gallery.php’);
```

as per instructions. I also tried:

```
include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . ‘/acf-gallery/acf-gallery.php’ );
```

But this does not work either.

This works fine on my local machine but when I upload this onto a web server I get an error message. The error I am getting is:

```
include_once(acf-gallery/acf-gallery.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I believe this is due to the path being incomplete or incorrect.

Is there another way of including this in PHP that will find path regardless of the server?

Comment: It means it can't find the file. Check inside you plugin folder where its located. I believe the file you trying to load isn't inside the stylesheet directory. But inside the plugin installation directory. So `wp-content/plugins/'plugin-name'`

Comment: I tried include_once('wp-content/plugins/acf-gallery/acf-gallery.php'); but this does not work either!?

Comment: acf-gallery is not the name of the plugin no? The plugin you're using is ACF. Just read documentation here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: acf-gallery is an add-on of the AFC. I have read their documentation which says to include include_once(‘acf-gallery/acf-gallery.php’); in the functions file. And it does work locally but now the files are on the server the plugin add-on is not being picked up. Documentation does not cover this possibility.

Comment: Are you sure the `file` you're trying to `include` is at that `location`? Show me a screenshot of the directory tree if possible.